# Prove that a morphism $\alpha$ of $Fun(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ is an isomorphism iff each component $\alpha_A$, is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm a computational engineer starting with a course of Introduction to Category Theory, and perhaps is extremely basic what I'm asking but I'm trying to learn how to make proofs in category theory working with the very basic concepts, but I just can't figure things out right now. Can you help me?

Thank you!

> Consider a small category $\mathcal{A}$ and the functor category $Fun(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$. Prove that a morphism $\alpha$ of $Fun(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ (a natural transformation) is an isomorphism if, and only if, each component $\alpha_A$, $A\in \mathcal{A}$, is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Which direction are you having trouble with?

Comment: what is a computational engineer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F,G:\mathcal A\rightarrow\mathcal B$ are functors and $\alpha:F\stackrel{\bullet}{\rightarrow}G$ is a natural transformation
such that $\alpha_{A}:F\left(A\right)\rightarrow G\left(A\right)$
is invertible for each object $A\in\mathcal A$ then it can be shown that the inverses $\alpha_{A}^{-1}:G\left(A\right)\rightarrow F\left(A\right)$
are the components of a natural transformation $G\stackrel{\bullet}{\rightarrow}F$.

We have $\alpha_{A}\circ\alpha_{A}^{-1}=\text{id}_{G\left(A\right)}$
and $\alpha_{A}^{-1}\circ\alpha_{A}=\text{id}_{F\left(A\right)}$
for each object $A\in\mathcal{A}$, so this natural transformation
appears to be the inverse of $\alpha$.

If conversely $\alpha:F\stackrel{\bullet}{\rightarrow}G$ is a natural
isomorphism and $\beta:G\stackrel{\bullet}{\rightarrow}F$ denotes
its inverse then $\alpha\circ\beta=\text{id}_{G}$ and $\beta\circ\alpha=\text{id}_{F}$
wich comes the same as $\alpha_{A}\circ\beta_{A}=\text{id}_{G\left(A\right)}$
and $\beta_{A}\circ\alpha_{A}=\text{id}_{F\left(A\right)}$ for each
object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$. This shows that the $\alpha_{A}$ are
all invertible.

Comment: Drhab's proof is just fine (of course). You'll find much the same argument as the proof for Theorem 21 in these [Notes on Basic Category Theory](http://logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/CategoryTheoryNotes_v8.pdf) -- which I mention because the Notes spell out lots of elementary proofs in detail, useful if you want to "learn how to make proofs in category theory working with the very basic concepts".

Comment: Thank you Peter and thank you drhab, appreciate your help

Comment: Glad to help! And @PeterSmith, I just realized that did not only provide that useful link but also the useful "Notes" behind it. Nice meeting you!